# Doubts about the SQLite interface in Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Ok, so I just learnt about the SQLite API in android.
All the tutorials talk about creating a helper class which extends the SQLIteOpenHelper. There is a constructor which as I understood creates the database and there is a onCreate callback which is used to create all the tables the first time the database is created. Till here, OK.

My doubts are:
Suppose, I create a database from one activity/class. My helper class is called DatabaseHelper. So, if I want to access the database from that creator class itself, then no problem. I just use the instance of DatabaseHelper which I would have created and then use that to access and work on the database.

But, how will I work on the same database from some other activity which needs to access the database. My doubt here is that since in this class I would have to create a new DatabaseHelper object, won't that go through the super constructor call and the onCreate callback again. And won't that be a problem?
What effects will it have on the database.

I am basically not able to understand how can I create a database once in my app and then just it anywhere from the app.

Any help appreciated. Links to good sites will be highly helpful.

Comment: And, if I make a global class which works with the database, what happens when I shut down the app and then the next time I open it, the same doubt of mine in different activities pops up. Won't it have to go through all the constructor and callbacks again?

Comment: You normally use a global class. The database is retained upon app closing. It's only created once, unless you don't change the DATABASE_VERSION. Or when you uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein the db is retained upon  app closing, that part is Ok. My doubt there is what happens when I start the app again. This time when I use my helper class again by creating an instance of it, won't it go through the callbacks again. What happens then? Will it go through the super constructor and give me an error because the db is already present. Or do I have to explicitly check wether db is present or not and then try to use the database. I am not able to understand the mechanism which I am not able to understand by the resources online.

Comment: What's not clear in `It's only created once`?

Comment: Can you tell me what happens when the super constructor is called with the name of a database which already exists. In that case, will the super constructor give an error, or will it return the same database when I call getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase()?

Comment: It will return the existing database without recreating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a constructor which as I understood creates the database

No. The database will not be created until you call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` for the first time.

> My doubt here is that since in this class I would have to create a new DatabaseHelper object

If you will have multiple components and threads using the database, have a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper` that everything uses.

> won't that go through the super constructor call and the onCreate callback again

No, because the database already exists. `onCreate()` is only called if the database does not exist at the time of `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()`.

Comment: thanks, the last point was the one which was bugging me, but I wasnt able to frame my question properly.